# Broken calculator

Tags: code-golf

The functions receives 5 numbers, let's call them a, b, c, d and e
You must display two numbers.
First one is (((a + b) - c) * d) % e = f
Second one is (((a + b) - c) * d - f) / e

```
Input:             Output:
7  5  9  3 8       1 1
1  2  3  4 5       0 0
19 25 9  7 11      3 22
21 12 99 3 13      -3 -15
21 12 99 3 -4      -2 49
```

Requirement: You are not allowed to use '***+***' '***-***' '*******' '***/***' symbols (or equivalent) when doing the calculation. You may however use '***%***' symbol (or equivalent) when doing the calculation.
By equivalent I meant that you are not allowed to use functions such as `BigInteger.add()` (**I am looking at you java users**).

Shortest code wins.

EDIT: as Peter suggested a clarification. All input numbers are int, and will never be 0

Comment: How will you measure speed? If you mean efficiency maybe comparing big-O values is better. Also, I think you mean `(((a+b)-c)*d-f)/e` for the second one.

Comment: @marinus sorry I have edited the question to shortest code wins. I guess there is no point to measure speed.

Comment: What type of number?

Comment: @Quincunx what do you mean by what kind of number? I believe all input numbers are integers, nor do I think that it is possible to get anything except integers for output.

Comment: Three questions: why is this entitled "Broken calculator"? How are you defining % with negative arguments? And is e guaranteed to be non-zero?

Comment: I think the 4th output should be `10 -16`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I call it broken calculator because my calculator had + button fall out which caused me to think up of this question. % with negative numbers yields negative numbers try it. and all numbers are guaranteed to be anything except 0.

Comment: @alephalpha here goes: 21 + 12 = 33 - 99 = -66 * 3 = -198 Next we do -198 % 13 which yields us -3 next we -198 - (-3) = -195 / 13 = -15

Comment: As @alephalpha points out (and is also apparent in my [Forth-based answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/broken-calculator/15364#15364) below), it's worth noting that the behaviour of the modulo operation can vary by language when negative values are involved.  As the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) says, a "naive definition breaks down and programming languages differ in how these values are defined."  Here's a good paper on [Division and Modulus for Computer Scientists](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/download/papers/divmodnote-letter.pdf).

Comment: @DarrenStone I will accept that. I only put modulus in there because I wanted to see all answers as int, and whenever division is done, perfect int can not be obtained without modulus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mathematica, 54 chars

I just use dot product.

```
f={Mod@##,Quotient@##}&[{{#,#2,#3}.{1,1,-1}}.{#4},#5]&
```

Example:

```
f[19, 25, 9, 7, 11]
```

> {3, 22}

Answer (score 5):

### Forth, 323 chars

```
: u 2dup ;
: p swap ;
: t -rot ;
: a u xor t and begin ?dup while 2* u xor t and repeat ;
: n invert 1 a ;
: m dup 0 < if p n p n then 0 p 0 ?do over a loop nip ;
: d dup 0 < t p dup 0 < t abs p abs p 0
begin t u <= while over n a rot 1 a repeat 2drop t xor if n then ;
: y 4 roll 4 roll a 3 roll n a rot m p u mod . d . ;
```

The forbidden arithmetic operations are defined in terms of binary operations. The core Forth word `mod` is used as the equivalent of `%`.

The final word `y` is the top-level function that accepts five numbers and prints two numbers as output.

Answer (score 3):

**C++ 503 characters**

```
#include<iostream>
#define I int
#define R return
#define T (I x,I y)
I A T{I a,b;do{a=x&y;b=x^y;x=a<<1;y=b;}while(a);R b;}
I N(I v){R A(~v,1);}
I S T{R A(x,N(y));}
I V(I v){R v<0?N(v):v;}
I M T{I a=0;I i=0;while(i<V(x)){i=A(i,1);a=A(a,y);}R x<0?S(0,a):a;}
I D T{I a=0;x=y==0?0:x;while(M(V(y),a)<V(x))a=A(a,1);R M(y==0?0:S(A(a,1),(x%y==0?1:2)),x<0^y<0?N(1):1);}
void C(I a,I b,I c,I d,I e){I g,f;f=(g=M(S(A(a,b),c),d))%e;std::cout<<f<<' '<<D(S(g,f),e);}
I main(I a){I b,c,d,e;std::cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;C(a,b,c,d,e);}
```

I get the same results as your examples except for the last two, I get -3 -15 and -2 49 respectively.  This is the same result that I get from the following...

```
int f = (((a + b) - c) * d) % e;
std::cout << f << ' ' << (((a + b) - c) * d - f) / e;
```

Comment: You can use `I` instead of `void` without returning anything, and it will still compile (at least on g++.) You can also shave some characters off by doing `I g,f;f=(g=M(S(A(a,b),c),d))%e;std::cout<<f<<' '<<D(S(g,f),e);`.

Comment: also `main(I a){I b,c,d,e;`

Comment: @marinus edited answer with your suggestions

Comment: I am sorry, your calculation was right. I was the one who made an error. I like your answer :)

Comment: @Quillion it was a good challenge